# BizTalk SharePoint Adapter and SharePoint Online permissions to update SharePoint lists

Tags: office365, biztalk, sharepoint-online, biztalk-2016

I would like to know what permissions are required to be able to update a SharePoint list from BizTalk using SharePoint Adapter (CSOM). Site provider only want to grant permissions necessary, and hence I need to know the common denominator.

I am not a SharePoint specialist, but it seems like you need to be in order to know what permissions to grant. E.g when adding to list, it seems like "lookup user information" is needed to retrieve user's username for the created by column. I.e you need to know what SharePoint does, to be able to get it right.

List contains standard columns, plus a few standard columns like lookup (i provide an ID), date and number. Related list from where values are looked up is similar.

Must I run BizTalk host instance with same account, or is providing credentials in adapter configuration sufficient?

Do I need permissions on both site AND list, and what permissions are needed in both in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now and have a theory about it:

In order for BizTalk Adapter to be able to do *handshake* with SharePoint, the host must use credentials known by SharePoint, and have sufficient rights to do so. BizTalk uses "Windows Identity Foundation"-library to call SharePoint, and from SharePoint's perspective BizTalk is a "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor". Hence the setting "Add and edit pages" (directly translated from Swedish) for the site must be activated for the user
("Behörighetsnivåer" > "Webbplatsbehörigheter" > "Lägg till och anpassa sidor").

At site level, you also must activate "Use remote interface" (directly translated from 
Swedish), which includes Client SharePoint Object Model (CSOM)
("Behörighetsnivåer" > "Webbplatsbehörigheter" > "Använd fjärrgränssnitt").

Then, after having gained access to the site itself, you need to provide specific rights for the operation to be done. In my case I needed to be able to add item to list, update etc.

One thing I have noted is that the handshake performed is saved to message's contexts. Meaning, if you have got a new message instance, (previous) handshake is added to the message context. If handshake failed, the message also fails and cannot be re-tried, but must be terminated.

Second thing I noted regarding handshake was that when adding rights, it was synchronised directly. However, if I revoked the rights, I needed to restart hosts (to re-handshake, I suppose).

As I said, a theory...

**EDIT:**

Actually, after a while it did not work. Again.

I needed to add permission Manage lists (yes, correct, PERMISSION TO ADMINISTRATE ALL LISTS ON THE SITE) in order for BizTalk Adapter to work.

After applying this setting I get the following message in eventlog:

The Windows SharePoint Services adapter has completed gathering the list and document library information from the SharePoint site .

Turns out that BizTalk SharePoint Adapter is dependent on getting lists of items in the site, including lists. Seems like it keeps this metadata about the SharePoint site for a while. It is possible to deactivate setting Manage lists, until it tries to reload the metadata again - then it will fail!

Note that some forums say that it is enough to set Contribute for adapter user, but Manage lists is not included in Contribute. So, it can not be enough.

Strange thing Microsoft do not give any information about what permissions are needed. Who developed this adapter? Should be able to give information about this!